# Extend Ace Editor highlighter

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

How to extend Ace (ace.ajax.org) highlighter to create link for each class identifier?

Straightforward approach doesn't work

```
$(function() {
     $('.ace_identifier').css("background-color","black");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/igos/qLAvN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.ace_identifier').css("background-color","black");`
doesn't work because ace creates dom nodes asynchronously

adding this css works
`.ace_identifier{background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}` works
http://jsbin.com/izecit/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, but css will not create a link. <a href=""></a>

Comment: if you need to modify dom use `editor.renderer.on("afterRender", ...)` http://jsbin.com/anufuz/3/edit